# Using SELECT in USING clause in ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table1 with column 'abc' with type as character varying
I want it to be modified to bigint.
The column values should be replaced with a value from external table like a foreign key reference,
i.e id corresponding to entry of this value in table2
How can i do it?
My attempt was :

```
 ALTER TABLE table1 ALTER COLUMN abc TYPE bigint USING SELECT some_id from table2 where col1=abc
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the subselect in parentheses?

Comment: Yes,I did. We cannot use subquery inside 'using' clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use a query in this context. Create a function:

```
create or replace function get_some_id(varchar)
returns bigint language sql as $$
    select some_id from table2 where col1 = $1
$$;

alter table table1 alter column abc type bigint using get_some_id(abc);
```